# Can I extend the Swift reserved word "enum"?

Tags: swift, enums

For example, I want to add something like this:

```
extension enum : T {
    convenience init? (rawData: T?) -> enum? {
        guard let rawData = rawData else { return nil; }
        return self.init(rawData: rawData);
    }
}
```

I know this is probably not a best case of why I need to extend the enum, but I just want to explore the possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you cannot do thinks like that. That does not make sense. You could extend `RawRepresentable` protocol though.

Comment: @Sulthan: Oops, had not seen your updated comment.

Comment: @MartinR I do, but I don't understand by what he exactly means of extending RawRepresentable protocol. Although I do know now from your answer. :D

Comment: @MartinR It took me a while to understand what he was trying to do.

Comment: @Sulthan actually, I'm exploring the possibilities if I can do *something else* too by extending enum. That's why I didn't explicitly wrote what I intend to do with the code above, because my main question is whether extending enum is possible or not, and if possible, how. But from the answer, I get some new information though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) in “The Swift Programming Language” (emphasis added):

> Extensions add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol **type.**

`enum` is a keyword, not a type, therefore an `extension enum` cannot
be defined.

If your intention is to instantiate an enumeration value from an
optional raw value, then you can define a [“protocol extension”](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521):

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    init?(rawData: RawValue?) {
        guard let rawData = rawData else { return nil }
        self.init(rawValue: rawData)
    }
}
```

This adds a new initializer to all types conforming to the
`RawRepresentable` protocol, in particular to all enumeration types
with a raw value type.

Example:

```
enum Foo: String {
    case a
    case b
}

print(Foo(rawData: "a"))  // Optional(Foo.a)
print(Foo(rawData: "x"))  // nil
print(Foo(rawData: nil))  // nil
```

Comment: Yes. Awesome. I'm curious though, of why the extension to `RawRepresentable` can make `enum` able to instantiate from optional `RawData`. Because in my logic, the code looks like it modifies the parameter, not the instantiating process itself. If enum still can't instantiate from optional, no matter if the RawData now can accept optional, it will still incompatible, right?

Comment: @ChenLiYong: I am not sure if I understand your question. `init?(rawData: RawValue?)` defines a new failable init method which either returns nil, or unwraps the argument and calls the existing `init?(rawValue:)` of the RawRepresentable protocol.

Comment: @ChenLiYong It doesn't make `enum` instantiate from an optional value, it makes types that implement `RawRepresentable` able to instantiate from an optional. As it happens, all `enum`s that have a raw value (i.e. everything declared in the form `enum MyType: Type { ... }`) adopt `RawRepresentable`

Comment: Alright, great. Btw, @MartinR, turns out that after I implement the extension, my code to instantiate enum with rawData that I supplied with optional string still giving me error: `Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` I have copied and pasted your code exactly like it is, and I don't suppose that the code needs some modification, as it's already general. Or do I need to make some modification?

Comment: @ChenLiYong: that works with a string-based enum as well, without modification. I have updated the example.

Comment: @MartinR I'm very thankful for your help, but it still didn't work. I have updated the question to include some part of the actual code I use to make it clear.

Comment: @ChenLiYong: It should be `Target(rawData: target)` in order to call the newly defined initializer, not `Target(rawValue: target)`

Comment: @MartinR ah I see! I missed that little detail!!